# modrewrite question

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

I am having a problem with modrewrite using the below rule.
I am getting an 404 error because the rule doesn't seem to work.
can someone provide a solution on how to get it working?

```
RewriteRule ^/catalogue/([^/\.]+)/results.html$ /search.php?data=$1 [L]
```

it should process urls like the following but gives me a 404:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/catalogue/europe/germany/results.html
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^catalogue/(.+?)/results.html$ /search.php?data=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

You example url is not affected by your rewrite rule; using `[^/\.]+` you are allowing all characters except the forward slash and the dot, so `europe/germany` does not match because it has a forward slash.

I don´t know what you want to allow exactly, but for your example url you could use something like:

```
RewriteRule ^/catalogue/([a-zA-Z/]+)/results.html$ /search.php?data=$1 [L]
```

which would allow `a` to `z` (upper and lower case) and the forward slash.

Answer (score 1):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^/catalogue/(.+?)/results.html$ /search.php?data=$1 [l]
```

Your rule isn't working because of your capturing pattern:

```
[^/\.]+
```

basically means:

```
Match anything that is not a / or a . for as many times as possible.
```

But it will stop at the first next / in the url, which causes it not to match anything